# Open Excel file and excute macros

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to open an Excel file and run the macros `ActionImporter` and `ActionExporter` from VBScript.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next

Dim AppExcel
Dim repertoireMISAJOURComplete
Dim nomDuFichier

repertoireMISAJOURComplete = "G:\Pole recrutement et mobilite\Testoutil\Serveur_V2.1.1.xlsm"     

nomDuFichier = "Serveur_V2.1.1.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= repertoireMISAJOURComplete

Set AppExcel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
AppExcel.Visible = True
'On Error Resume Next
'ouvre le classeur
AppExcel.Workbooks.Open (repertoireMISAJOURComplete)
'peut exécuter une macro
'à l'ouverture (ôter l'apostrophe)
'devant AppExcel.Run "Test"
'et changer le nom de la macro :
Windows(nomDuFichier).Activate

Sheets("Administration Serveur").Select
Application.Run nomDuFichier & "!'ActionImporter'"

Windows(nomDuFichier).Activate

Sheets("Administration Serveur").Select
Application.Run nomDuFichier & "!'ActionExporter'"
Set AppExcel = Nothing

'quitte VBS
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Step #1 in VBScript debugging: remove global `On Error Resume Next` and actually see what fails. Your issue is probably caused by the fact that your VBScript contains VBA code. See [here](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) for translation guidelines.

Comment: Also won't help that you tried to open a Workbook before you created the Excel instance...

Comment: From VBScript's point of view -- `Windows`, `Sheets`, etc. are just undeclared, uninitiated variables.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution so i share with you :

```
Option Explicit
Dim args, objExcel
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open "G:\Testoutil\Serveur_V2.1.1.xlsm",,,,"myPassword"
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "ActionImporter"

objExcel.Run "ActionExporter"

objExcel.Quit
```